# improve performance Bulk load in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, bulkinsert

We generate 240,000 records per second and save in csv file. Now we want to load them in Cassandra.
I used 3 methods:

1. sstableloader : we generate sstable and use sstableloader command to load them, but this method takes a long time to complete and the number of rows per second is : 15,000
2. JmxBulkLoader: this method is better than sstableloader. Number of  rows/s is 17,000
3. copy: not proper for bulk and crash when used

System configuration:

> CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2697 v3 @ 2.60GHz. 56 Cores
> RAM: 64 G
> Hard Disk:
>
> ```
> 1TB local for cassandra nodes and 
> 10TB in a network drive (data files stored in this hard)
> ```

We have 2 nodes in this machine.

Thanks.

Comment: when you say jmx what exactly do you mean? You seem to be pretty informed on the topic, that's pretty much (other than jmx which I don't understand what it is) and writing your own import app ... just in theory you could generate sstables directly on the nodes and then call nodetool refresh, but what you described is pretty much it (interesting question) but there might be some ways I'm not aware :) (as always)

Comment: I suppose saving in to Cassandra would be faster than saving to a CSV file.  What I would do, use some cache service like redis and then save the records to Cassandra.

Comment: @MarkoŠvaljek we use jmx to connect to cassandra from java driver and send data to cassandra.

Comment: @Gunwant . if we use redis. because cassandra load is low so ram may be full. and write each row directly in cassandra is very slow, so we write it in file

Comment: @HamidMamdoohi jmx to provide data to connect makes sense ... but sending data over jmx to cassandra is another thing. Anyway, you pretty much listed all the options. To be honest, it's little questionable if redis would achieve 240 000 records per second. You might try option 2 with multiple clients then but still you would be looking at 10x speed increase, without adding more cassandra nodes and clients it's hard. Also are you sure you are timing the 240 records per second generating correctly and are counting in the actual time for the records to land on disk?

Comment: Then again when I see the number of cores that you have I'm suspecting that you are using the driver wrongly. Try having just one session object, make prepared statement and execute the querries with async. This should go significantly faster ... 100 000 req/s or even more should not be problematic for your machine. If you are using relatively simple data (not multi kilobyte data in one insert)

Comment: @MarkoŠvaljek thanks for your comment, we generate between 200 and 240 record per second. but how many node must be used ?

Comment: can you please edit your question and post ls -lah of all the files on the disk, single sample record (obfuscate if it's some sensitive data) ... also post a code of a class that is doing the import (of what you call the jmx) Then somebody might help you ... this discussion is at the moment a lot of theoretical talk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can fetch the records from csv file or directly from source and load it into Cassandra using the Java's ExecuteAsync method .

Have a Look at blog : -
https://blog.knoldus.com/2017/01/31/cassandra-tips-and-techniques/